# Use Electron with Bootstrap 5 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, electron, bootstrap-5

I am creating my first electron app and wanted some styling with bootstrap 5.
So I:

(1) installed via *npm i --save bootstrap jquery popper.js* the necessary modules

(2) created a main.scss including *@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';*

(3) put into the head of my index.html:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./contents/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script>let $ = require('jquery');</script>
    <script>require('popper.js');</script>
    <script>const bootstrap = require('bootstrap');</script>
```

After that I copy+paste a nav bar out of the bootstrap documentation. I dont know what is wrong and I didnt find any answer. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 5 doesn't use jQuery any longer.

Just do:

`npm i --save bootstrap@latest`